# "to break hard" in Esperanto

Tags: single-word-requests

The English expression, "to break hard", as in, "with a car rental, I use the breaks harder than with my own car". What would be this expression in Esperanto?

Google Translate gives "uzi la paŭzojn pli malfacile", but somehow, that sounds lame. Is there something better?

Comment: "malfacile" is certainly wrong. "hard" in English can mean many things, among them "the opposite of soft" ("malmola"), but also "difficult" ("malfacila"), or strongly ("forte"). Here, you're looking for the latter, thus "forte" should probably be the adverb used.

Comment: ”pauxzo” means ”break” as in ”pause”, you mean ”bremsoj”

Comment: @das-g - why not make your comment a proper answer?

Comment: The words [_break_](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/romp.html#lng) (to make unusable) and [_brake_](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/brems.html#lng) (to use the brakes on a vehicle) are homophones, they sound exactly the same but have completely different meanings. It's hard to find _bremsi_ (= _brake_) if you are looking for _break_ (= _rompi_).

Comment: "why not make your comment a proper answer?" Because it only answers one part of the question - it doesn't treat the "to break" part at all (because I couldn't remember the Esperanto word for that.) I might make it _part_ of an answer later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## "break" vs. "brake"

As Vidamuzo pointed out in [a comment](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5485/to-break-hard-in-esperanto?noredirect=1#comment5830_5485), you probably mean "to brake" (take an action to decelerate a vehicle), not "to break" (destroy something, or rupture it into two or more pieces).

Similarly, to do that, you'd use the vehicle's "brake(s)", not a "break" (interruption of an activity or of work, a pause).

The Esperanto words for "to brake" and for "brake" (the noun) are "bremsi" and "bremso". ("paŭzo" would be the "interruption" meaning of "break" (noun).)

## what kind of "hard"?

"hard" in English can mean many things, among them "the opposite of soft" ("malmola"), but also "difficult" ("malfacila"), or strongly / with much force ("forte"). Here, you're looking for the latter, thus "forte" should probably be the adverb used, maybe with a "tre".

## putting it together

Thus

> to brake hard

would become

> (tre) forte bremsi

or (at your preference)

> bremsi (tre) forte

Conjugated:

> Sofia brakes hard.

> Sofia (tre) forte bremsas.

---

> Sofia braked hard. / Sofia did brake hard.

> Sofia (tre) forte bremsis.

---

> Sofia will brake hard. / Sofia is going to brake hard.

> Sofia (tre) forte bremsos.

Comment: Superb answer, das-g. Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Mi bremsas pli forte

Mi premas la bremson pli forte/profunde